# Request forwarding on button click

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jsf-1.2

I am new to JSF and ADF technology.

I have a page index.jspx which gets loaded when the application starts. The page has a submit button.This page displays a `hello` message which I am setting in the managed bean `DemoBean`.

What I want is when the user clicks the submit button, the request will be forwarded to another page which is called welcome.jspx and the same msg gets displayed

Comment: There are several good introductions on JSF. A 'summary'  (and other interesting things) by BalusC can be found at https://jsf.zeef.com/ Please check those out.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about *JSF Page Navigation*.

Anymore something like this should works for you:

**YourBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class YourBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
   <h:inputText value="#{yourBean.name}"></h:inputText>
   <h:commandButton value="Join" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

**welcome.xhtml**

```
<h2>Welcome #{yourBean.name}!</h2>
```

In any case I suggest you to send the parameter in a request if you don't need Session.

**See more:**

- [Hello World Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/)
- [Page Navigation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_page_navigation.htm)

Comment: OP is using JSF 1.x. This answer targets JSF 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Shantanu

You should go through ADF Basics before starting , read some oracle docs, refer a good book and blogs

No need to use any HTML page or anything 
Just drop two pages in adfc-config.xml (default un-bounded taskFlow) and put a control flow between them .

Then in Action property of button refer that controlFlow name , this will navigate to second page on click of button

Once check - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows.htm

Also go through- http://www.awasthiashish.com/2014/01/how-to-learn-oracle-adf-from-scratch.html